# Bash : Poll for a file creation and terminate if exits

Tags: bash, shell-script

I'm trying to write a script that traps a exit signal and terminate. Instead of using the usual bash trap method, I would like to monitor a file creation every 10 seconds and cleanup some stuff before termination.

Here is what I have tried:

```
poll_time=10 // poll every 10 seconds
((term_time=$SECONDS+240)) // monitor until 4 min from current script time exec

while (( $SECONDS < $term_time)) do
    if [[ -r $some_path/file.txt ]]; then
        cleanup_function
        exit
fi
sleep ${poll_time}
done

//if file doesnt exit continue with below code
//blah blah blah ....
```

Is there a better way to do this? will above lines of code work?

Comment: It won't work because of your syntax errors. Add a semicolon or a newline before your do, and use `# blah` for comments.

Answer (score 5):

`inotifywait` from `inotify-tools` is what you need (to look at at least). Line like this will do the same trick your script is intended to do:

```
inotifywait -e create --timeout 240 "${some_path}/file.txt" && { cleanup_function; exit ; }
```

with the difference `inotifywait` works in event-based manner, so no polling or sleeping required.

Comment: I'm using buysbox and I guess inotifywait is not supported on that ?

Comment: @richie BusyBox has builtin tool `inotifyd` serving the same purposes. Though it has limited functionality compared to `inotify-tools`, e.g. no timeout option or need to have separate script to handle event. Alternatively, you can try and install `inotify-tools` manually.